# Teamviewer access Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, rdp

Is it possible to access Ubuntu which is installed via Vagrant/Oracles Virtual Box on my windows machine via Team viewer so I can actually see the Ubuntu GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you should be able to.

However, because of the fact that Vagrant boxes are normally base install (minimal) of a distribution, you may have to install X and a desktop environment (GNOME/KDE) or some light weight Window manager (lxde, e17, openbox, fluxbox, xmonad etc...) as well as the Teamviewer client before you can connect to it and see the desktop.

For example, if you want to install lxde, you `vagrant ssh` and get into the box, run `sudo apt-get install lxde`.

See more: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Ubuntu